# Can I use Leaflet plugin and Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am using Leaflet and Mapbox's tile layer.

As far as I know, it's a good thing that I don't use `mapbox.js` because its support is no more active. So I am using Leaflet.

Now, if I want to switch to map loads/vector tiles/webgl instead of pricing per tile requests, what should I do? should I stop using Leaflet and start using Mapbox GL JS?  or I can just use Mapbox's GL tiles and put it into Leaflet's tile and that will be all?

Answer (score 2):

If you want page-load pricing, you need to use Mapbox-GL-JS version 1.0 or later.